# Simulate camera with distortion in pyBullet

Tags: opengl, camera, camera-calibration, pybullet

I am trying to configure a camera in pyBullet based on intrinsic and extrinsic parameters obtained from calibrating a real camera.

### What I have

The camera is calibrated with OpenCV, giving me a camera matrix

```
|f_x  0  c_x|
| 0  f_y c_y|
| 0   0   1 |
```

and a vector of distortion coefficients

```
(k_1, k_2, p_1, p_2, k_3)
```

(I further have the pose of the camera but this is not relevant for the actual question, so I leave it out here.)

### What I already did

Unfortunately the `computeProjectionMatrix` function of pyBullet is a bit limited.  It assumes `f_x = f_y` and `c_x, c_y` being exactly at the center of the image, which is both not true for my camera.  Therefore I compute the projection matrix myself as follows (based on [this](https://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html)):

```
projection_matrix = [
    [2/w * f_x,  0,  (w - 2c_x)/w,  0],
    [0,  2/h * f_y,  (2c_y - h)/h,  0],
    [0, 0, A, B],
    [0, 0, -1, 0],
]
```

where `w,h` are width and height of the image, `A = (near + far)/(near - far)` and `B = 2 * near * far / (near - far)`, `near` and `far` defining the range on the z-axis that is included in the image (see `pybullet.computeProjectionMatrix`).

### What is still missing (my actual question)

The above already gives me better results but the rendered images it still don't match exactly with the real images.  I suspect one reason for this might be that the distortion is not taken into account.

So finally coming to my question:

**How can I implement distortion for the simulated camera using the parameters I got from calibrating the real camera?**

Is there a way I can integrate this in the projection matrix?  If not, is there an other way?

Comment: What does a physics system (Bullet) have to do with a property of rendering (camera distortion)? The physics system just determines where in the virtual space an object is.

Comment: "Aside from physics simulation, pybullet supports to rendering, with a CPU renderer and OpenGL visualization and support for virtual reality headsets."

Comment: @NicolBolas pyBullet also provides rendering functionality.  I am using pyBullet's `getCameraImage` function which takes the projection matrix mentioned here as input.

Comment: Generally nonlinear distortion cannot be done with a matrix.

Comment: Ah, right, I didn't think about the non-linearity.  I solved it now by first rendering the image without distortion and then distorting the result.  I'll write that up in an answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, non-linear distortion cannot be integrated into the matrices.  What I am doing now is to first render the image without distortion and then distort the resulting image in a second step, using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58131157/2095383).

The image shrinks a bit due to the distortion, so when keeping the image size fixed there will be some empty area at the edges of the image.  To compensate for this, I render the image at a slightly larger size than needed and then crop after distorting.  Note that the centre point `(c_x, c_y)` needs to be adjusted accordingly, when increasing the size.

To illustrate with some pseudo code:

```py
desired_image_size = (width, height)

# add 10% padding on each size
padding = desired_image_size * 0.1
render_image_size = desired_image_size + 2 * padding

# shift the centre point accordingly (other camera parameters are not changed)
c_x += padding[0]
c_y += padding[1]

# render image using the projection_matrix as described in the question
image = render_without_distortion(projection_matrix, camera_pose)

image = distort_image(image)

# remove the padding
image = image[padding[0]:-padding[0], padding[1]:-padding[1]]
```

This results in images that match very well with the ones from the real camera.

The complete implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/open-dynamic-robot-initiative/trifinger_simulation/blob/8bb502bd3405f99f457cd13d187634e2fc7360a9/python/trifinger_simulation/camera.py#L179).

Answer (score 0):

I searched extensively to find a compact answer to constructing the view and projection matrices using calibrated K and ROS TF extrinsic poses but to my amusement, I found none.

I wrote and tested the following two functions which computes the matrices required for simulating real cameras in pybullet. Hopefully it will be useful:

```
from pyquaternion import Quaternion
import numpy as np


def cvK2BulletP(K, w, h, near, far):
    """
    cvKtoPulletP converst the K interinsic matrix as calibrated using Opencv
    and ROS to the projection matrix used in openGL and Pybullet.

    :param K:  OpenCV 3x3 camera intrinsic matrix
    :param w:  Image width
    :param h:  Image height
    :near:     The nearest objects to be included in the render
    :far:      The furthest objects to be included in the render
    :return:   4x4 projection matrix as used in openGL and pybullet
    """ 
    f_x = K[0,0]
    f_y = K[1,1]
    c_x = K[0,2]
    c_y = K[1,2]
    A = (near + far)/(near - far)
    B = 2 * near * far / (near - far)

    projection_matrix = [
                        [2/w * f_x,  0,          (w - 2*c_x)/w,  0],
                        [0,          2/h * f_y,  (2*c_y - h)/h,  0],
                        [0,          0,          A,              B],
                        [0,          0,          -1,             0]]
    #The transpose is needed for respecting the array structure of the OpenGL
    return np.array(projection_matrix).T.reshape(16).tolist()


def cvPose2BulletView(q, t):
    """
    cvPose2BulletView gets orientation and position as used 
    in ROS-TF and opencv and coverts it to the view matrix used 
    in openGL and pyBullet.
    
    :param q: ROS orientation expressed as quaternion [qx, qy, qz, qw] 
    :param t: ROS postion expressed as [tx, ty, tz]
    :return:  4x4 view matrix as used in pybullet and openGL
    
    """
    q = Quaternion([q[3], q[0], q[1], q[2]])
    R = q.rotation_matrix

    T = np.vstack([np.hstack([R, np.array(t).reshape(3,1)]),
                              np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])])
    # Convert opencv convention to python convention
    # By a 180 degrees rotation along X
    Tc = np.array([[1,   0,    0,  0],
                   [0,  -1,    0,  0],
                   [0,   0,   -1,  0],
                   [0,   0,    0,  1]]).reshape(4,4)
    
    # pybullet pse is the inverse of the pose from the ROS-TF
    T=Tc@np.linalg.inv(T)
    # The transpose is needed for respecting the array structure of the OpenGL
    viewMatrix = T.T.reshape(16)
    return viewMatrix
```

The above two functions give you the required matrices to get images from the pybullet environment like this:

```
projectionMatrix = cvK2BulletP(K, w, h, near, far)
viewMatrix = cvPose2BulletView(q, t)

_, _, rgb, depth, segmentation = b.getCameraImage(W, H, viewMatrix, projectionMatrix, shadow = True)
```

Above returns images without distortion. For this, you could use the answer provided earlier.